# How to persist/pass firebase authentication to webview from android native part?

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-authentication

Login and Sign in is happening in native part. I want to pass the authentication state of current user to webView so that authenticated user data can be retrieved.

What I have tried so far:

(a) I have tried to use custom token authentication but the token generation in native uses firebase admin dependency, and it is incompatible with firebase auth dependency, so unable to use this method.

(b) I have also tried to detect the authentication state using OnAuthStateChange() method in javascript but it is unable to detect the logged in authentication state of user.

Comment: Would you like to edit the question to show what you have so far, and where you are stuck in the implementation? There probably a lot of steps involved with this, and it would be helpful to see what the specific problem is.

Comment: The code in the webview doesn't know anything about the code running in native.  You are going to have to write code to get the user's ID token in native, then inject it into the webview, and use that to sign in the user again with JavaScript in the webview.

Comment: Do you mean custom token authentication? I have tried this but it needs firebase admin as dependency which is not working fine with other firebase dependencies and giving error.

Comment: @DougStevenson , I have a thought that if I make a https callable function to generate and return custom token from currentuser's uid and call that function in native part before loading webview and then pass the retrieved custom token to webview as a parameter. Then sign in with custom token in javascript. Is this a good approach or anything better can be done?